# @WithUserDetails annotation not working for Spring Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-security

I've got some tests written that I'm trying to run with a `@WithUserDetails` annotation. However, when I run it, it tells me it can't find my custom `UserDetailsService` implementation. How can I help the test class find this class?

Here's the stack trace for the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(value=user1, userDetailsServiceBeanName=)

    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:96)
    ... 31 more
```

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WithUserDetails("user1")
public class RecipeControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private RecipeService recipeService;

    @Mock
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Mock
    private IngredientService ingredientService;

    @Mock
    private InstructionService instructionService;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @InjectMocks
    private RecipeController recipeController;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(recipeController)
                .setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getIndex() throws Exception {
        List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        User user = new User();

        Recipe recipe = recipeBuilder();
        Recipe recipe2 = recipeBuilder();

        List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
        recipes.add(recipe);
        recipes.add(recipe2);

        when(userService.findByUsername("user1")).thenReturn(user);
        when(recipeService.findAll()).thenReturn(recipes);
        when(categoryService.findAll()).thenReturn(categories);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("login"));
    }
}
```

and here is my custom `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Component
public class DetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // Load user from database (throw exception if not found)
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }

        // Return user object
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getRoles())
        );
    }
}
```

I should mention the application has no issues finding this class when I run it normally, it's just the test class that has issues finding it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Given you are using standaloneSetup you aren't loading an ApplicationContext thus no UserDetailsService bean exists. Take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html#test-mockmvc-securitycontextholder-rpp. You may also be interested in switching to MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup

Comment: @SeanCarroll thanks that helps a ton! If you'll make that an answer I'll give you the proper acknowledgement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are using standaloneSetup you aren't loading an ApplicationContext thus no UserDetailsService bean exists. If you haven't already take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-securitycontextholder-rpp. You may also be interested in switching to MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup

Comment: Sean, this link is dead now. Do you have an updated version of what it was pointing to?

Comment: Fixed dead link